# Randomly drawing from a hypercube in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider the n-cube (defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube)) with n>3. Suppose that it centered at the origin of the Cartesian plane and each edge has length 10.

I would like to write a piece of code in Matlab that allows me to randomly draw one point (with n coordinates) from this hypercube. Is there a way to do it without pre-defining a n-dimensional grid? In my particular application n=11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw 1 point from the volume of an n-dimensional hypercube with side `s`, with all points having equal probability, you call

```
s = 10;
point = (rand(1,n)-0.5)*s;
```

Replace the 1 with a larger number if you want to draw many points at once.

Comment: Where is the center? Is it be possible to use center different from the origin?

Answer (score 3):

Extending Jonas' answer, if you want to specify a center, do this:

```
center = [1.0 -1.0 2.0 -2.0 ...];
s = 10;
point = (rand(1,n)-0.5)*s + center;
```